# Establish Connection First, Redirect User Second

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jakarta-ee

I have an idea to make something pretty sweet but I'm not sure if it's possible. Here is an example of a very basic ajax function that I might use to establish a connection a server...

```
function getFakePage(userId)
{
    var ajaxObject, path, params;

    ajaxObject = getAjaxObject();
    params = "?userId=" + userId
    path = getInternalPath() + "someServlet" + params;

    ajaxObject.open("GET", path, true);
    ajaxObject.send();

    // On ready state change stuff here
}
```

So let's say I have a URL like this...

```
https://localhost:8443/Instride/user/1/admin
```

And I wanted to use javascript to redirect the user to this this URL. Normally I would just do this...

```
window.location = "https://localhost:8443/Instride/user/1/admin";
```

But my idea is to create a javascript **(no js frameworks please)** function that could combine the `ajax` code with the `window.location` code. Basically what I would like to accomplish is to create a connection with the server via ajax, send a servlet on that server the url I would like the user to be redirected to, and then redirect the user to that URL. So that for however long it takes the user to connect to my server from wherever they are in the world they see a loading icon instead of a blank white page.

So to clarify exactly what I am trying to accomplish; I do not want to put window.location within the success of my ajax function (because that would be encompass two round trips), and I do not want to return a huge chunk of HTML for the requested resource and add it to the page. I want to establish a connection to the server with ajax, send a servlet the URL the user wants to go to, and then somehow override the ajax function to redirect that user. Is this possible?

And I know some of you might think this is stupid but it's not when you're talking about overseas users with slow dial up connections staring at white pages. If it's possible, I'd love to hear some insight. Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to be different because of this AJAX call, vs. just redirecting to the page? Is it just the progress events? Have you looked at HTML 5 app cache? It will allow you to download the pages in the background, cache them, and instantly switch to them. But it requires a pretty modern browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me say that the best solution is finding what is causing the slowness and fixing it.

Now as to your question, yes you could do it.  You could even shoehorn it onto an existing application.  But it wouldn't be pretty.  And it comes with it's own set of problems.  But here are the steps:

1. Browser calls ajax cache service requesting "somepage.html"
2. Browser loads loading icon
3. Server creates somepage.html and caches it in a temporary cache, (ehcache or other library would be good, probably with file backing for the cache depending on size)
4. Server responds to ajax request with ID for cached page
5. Browser now redirects to "somepage.html?cacheId={cacheId}" where the id is from the ajax call.
6. Server uses a filter to see if any cache can be served up for the page instead of the actual page, thus speeding up the request.

Having said that, it would be better to just have the new page load quickly with a loading icon while it did any of the heavy lifting through ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the steps. I actually don't like your later suggestion though. That would incur more http requests which is what I do not want. I'd rather just make one round trip. But your steps rock and I appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: Either way you would need at least two round trips, one for ajax (either loading content or telling server to cache) and one for the page.  Also, if round trips are an issue, you can save a lot of round trips by base64 encoding images into css and inlining css and javascript.  I wouldn't suggest it, but that does lower round trips.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an AJAX request and a location change in one. If you want to do only one request you have to choose one of those methods. ie. return some data and replace content on your current page, or load a completely new page.

It doesn't make any sense to want to want to do both. What you *could* want is *stateful* URLs; where your URL matches the content displayed, even if that content comes from an AJAX request. In that case an easy solution is the use the `#` part of the URL which you can change freely (`window.location.hash`). Some modern browsers support changing the whole URL without causing the page to reload. I've used `#` with great success myself.

Comment: thank you for the information. I have experience with hashtags, and pushState so I know exactly what you are referring to. Just had an idea and wanted to know if it was possible. Sounded crazy when I was writing it but I thought I'd ask